# PHP OOP get all parent classes of a class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have class **Mercedes** and it has parent **Car** and Car has parent **Main**.
I want to get all parents from **Mercedes** Class

```
Mercedes extends Car 
Car extends Main
```

output should be something like this `mercedes<-Car<-Main`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

Comment: If your class needs to know its parent you are doing it wrong.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this question. First off, why do you need to know who the parent is? Second, why does your class inherit from "Main"? A **Mercedes** *is a* **Car**. But a **Car** *is not a* **Main**.

Comment: I have other implemented names I just entered as an example... I want to get a trace from first class till end of the tree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do:

```
function GetAllParents(instance) {
   return get_class(instance) . '<-' .
          implode('<-', array_reverse(class_parents(instance)));
}
```

Outputs all in the right order:

```
Mercedes<-Car<-Main
```

See documentation:

- http://php.net/class_parents
- http://php.net/implode

Answer (score 4):

try

```
print_r(class_parents(new Mercedes ));
```

For more :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php

or
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

it will output you as array so need to use [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/implode)

```
<?php echo implode('<-', class_parents(new Mercedes)); ?>
```

Comment: ♥ PHP. Function for every thing.